# WiX exclude certain file or certain file types under specific folder?

Tags: wix, wix3

I have used "HeatDirectory" to harvest all the files. But I need to remove all the (*.xml and *.pdb) files under the "bin" folder.

I am able to remove individual files with any extension. But, How to remove the certain file or certain file types under the particular folder?

Below is the XSLT i am using to remove file based on the extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="RemoveGlobal.asax.cs" 
match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'Global.asax.cs')]" use="@Id" 
/>
<xsl:key name="RemoveCsproj" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 
'.csproj')]" use="@Id" />

<xsl:template match="*[self::wix:Component or self::wix:ComponentRef] 
[key('RemoveGlobal.asax.cs', @Id)]" />  
<xsl:template match="*[self::wix:Component or self::wix:ComponentRef] 
[key('RemoveCsproj', @Id)]" />  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Simple answer: delete the files before calling heat. Keep your model clean.

Comment: these all are project's xml and pdb files which will generate during build. Also, harversting is keeping all the files. but publish action will not do the same and need to remove the certain files or file types from the folder.

Comment: Understood. You could have an MSBuild file that defines a copy of Include=**/*.* Exclude=**/*.pdb;**/*.xml"   tweak it until the dest directory looks exactly like your installed product and then call Heat.

Comment: It's also possible to go into each project and tell it to not generate PDBs, serialization DLLs and XML documentation files.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Chris. At this point of time, i am not looking for a solution to make it from VS project. Yes, I am aware that we can restrict the PDB and XML file from the build action. However, i am looking for suggestion to filter one or more files in the particular folder based on the extension.

Comment: You should propably ask this question tagged with `xslt`. Add a simplified input file and expected output file as example.